# ESP8266 in AP Mode -determining if a station is connected

Tags: esp8266, wifi, sleep

I have an ESP8266 running in AP mode using softAP and i want to conserve battery life.
I am wanting to turn on wifi and advertise SSID for 20 seconds. If no station connects to the ssid within the 20 seconds, I want to go to sleep for 1 minute, otherwise I do not sleep.

My problem is that I cannot get "WiFi.softAPgetStationNum()" working. when I build i get a message that this is not part of ESP8266WiFi class. I have attached simplified code.

Can someone help me to achieve this please?

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

//WIFI Access point setup
const char* Ssid = "SSID";
const char* Password = "Password";
IPAddress ip(10,0,0,10);
IPAddress gateway(10,0,0,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);
WiFiServer server(80);                    // Set web server port number to 
80


// GPIO pins
const int output_set = 5;
int delay_loop=0;

void setup() 
{
  // Data Direction
  pinMode(output_set, OUTPUT);

  // Output initial Values
  digitalWrite(output_set, LOW);

  WiFi.softAPConfig(ip,gateway,subnet);
  WiFi.softAP(Ssid,Password);
  server.begin();


// check to see if a station is connected to this AP. If no station 
connected within 20 sec timeframe, go to sleep.

while (WiFi.softAPgetStationNum()==0)              //loop here while no AP is connected to this station
{
    delay(1);
    delay_loop++;
    if (delay_loop>=20000)                          
    {

        ESP.deepSleep(60e6);                          //go to sleep for 60 sec -wake pin externally connected to reset pin
    } 
}
}

void loop()
{
   digitalWrite(output_set, HIGH);      //Flash led once station is connected
   delay(200);
   digitalWrite(output_set, LOW);
   delay(400);     
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Above code builds fine for me in PlatformIO and in Arduino IDE 1.8.3 using Arduino-ESP8266 version 2.4.1 and ESP8266WiFi library version 1.0.0. What version are you using?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, Arduino IDE Ver:1.8.5, ESP8266WiFi library Ver: 1.0.0.  I am unsure what Arduino-ESP8266 v2.4.1 is? are you able to clarify this?

Comment: I have: http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json added to my additional boards manager URL in preferences

Comment: That URL is correct. What version does boardmanager say you have for `esp8266`? (Tools->Board->Board manager)

Comment: it said 2.0.0, and I have now changed it to 2.4.1. My problem has now been solved. Thank you for your help with this. I continue to learn. Kudos.

Answer (score 2):

Followup answer from comments:

The issue was an outdated version of the ESP8266-Arduino framework. The function `WiFi.softAPgetStationNum()` is available in 2.4.1

For the sake of completeness: The function itself is simply a wrapper for the Espressif non-os SDK function:

```cpp
/**
 * Get the count of the Station / client that are connected to the softAP interface
 * @return Stations count
 */
uint8_t ESP8266WiFiAPClass::softAPgetStationNum() {
    return wifi_softap_get_station_num();
}
```

See [Espressif Non-OS SDK API reference](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/2c-esp8266_non_os_sdk_api_reference_en.pdf) chapter 3.5.36.

That function should also be available on older framework versions. However, upgrading is the recommended way to use that function.